# What is Meant by Hooting

Tags: technique, opera

I once heard a tenor refer to a soprano as having “hooted” while singing with him.  What exactly does that mean?

Comment: I suppose this was just a general derogatory remark on her singing. I do not think *hooting* is a standardized name for a vocal technique, at least I’ve never heard of such.

Comment: Perhaps a side effect of her having eaten too much hummus or baked beans before the performance?

Comment: I wonder if he meant *screeching*.